# requirejs returns undefined in asp.net core application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, requirejs

I installed requirejs nuget package and added to my `Index.cshtml` this:

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/js/scripts/tetromino-client/client.js"></script>
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
wwwroot
   |-js
     |-scripts
        |-tetromino-client
           |-client.js
           |-block.js
Views
  |-Home
     |-Index.cshtml
```

client.js

```
requirejs(["block"], function (Block) {
    var block = new Block(); // Block is undefined
    console.log(block.value);
});
```

block.js

```
function Block() {
    this.value = 50;
}
```

Requirejs cannot resolve block.js and returns undefined. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you exported `Block` using the RequireJS `define` syntax?

Comment: Thank you, I thought that `define()` was similar to `requirejs()`. I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is a `requirejs.config` call with `baseUrl`, telling RequireJS where to look for additional libraries:

```
requirejs.config({baseUrl: './js/scripts/tetromino-client'}):

requirejs(["block"], function (Block) {
    var block = new Block(); // Block is undefined
    console.log(block.value);
});
```

And then you need to use `define` syntax when defining the `block` module:

```
define(function () {
    function Block() {
        this.value = 50;
    }

    return Block;
});
```